How do I configure ESLint for jQuery?
I installed eslint globally using npm install -g eslint --save-dev and it create eslint.config.mjs in my WSL2 project directory.
I installed the jquery plugin globally using npm install -g eslint-plugin-jquery --save-dev but I cannot find where it was placed.
I tried to modify eslint.config.mjs for jquery.
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";

export default [
  {files: ["**/*.js"], languageOptions: {sourceType: "script"}},
  {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  {"plugins": ["jquery"],"extends": ["plugin:jquery/deprecated"]},
];

From my project directory I ran npx eslint build/may08/js/merged.min.js and got the error response:
Oops! Something went wrong! :(
ESLint: 9.2.0
A config object has a "plugins" key defined as an array of strings.
Flat config requires "plugins" to be an object in this form:

    {
        plugins: {
            jquery: pluginObject
        }
    }

I modified the last line to {plugins: jquery} but received the error:
Oops! Something went wrong! :(
ESLint: 9.2.0
ReferenceError: jquery is not defined
    at file:///home/jabrown/develop/jqproject/eslint.config.mjs?mtime=1715366321831:9:13
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:235:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:461:24)
    at async loadFlatConfigFile (/home/jabrown/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint.js:317:21)
    at async calculateConfigArray (/home/jabrown/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint.js:396:28)
    at async ESLint.lintFiles (/home/jabrown/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint.js:815:25)
    at async Object.execute (/home/jabrown/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli.js:500:23)
    at async main (/home/jabrown/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js:153:22)

Most of the configuration examples that I found still used eslintrc.js. Running ESLint on jquery source files should be in very common use. So how is it configured?


I installed the jquery plugin globally using npm install -g eslint-plugin-jquery --save-dev but I cannot find where it was placed.

To list where global node_modules exist:
npm -g list

To see the user-level installed:
npm list

To list the full configuration:
npm config ls -l

eslint would require dependencies, including eslint plugins to be installed in the current directory of the project, also known as the build directory, where node_modules will be. eslint will look only locally (within the folder) for eslint plugins. I presume that's why they can't be found.
duplicate: How to list npm user-installed packages

I found it under .npm-global/lib and listed in my home directory but not in the project directory.

npm install should install all dependencies in current directory (your project directory, where packages.json is).

I found package.json and package-lock.json in my home directory but only eslint.config.mjs in my jqproject directory.

depends how your project is setup. Based on your feedback, you may have also yarn and a configuration to reference jqproject.

Did not use yarn. I did run npx eslint --init. There is no package.json anywhere. We use a script to merge ~25 *.js files into one. I put /* global $ */ at the top and run npx eslint <file> from the command line. That works well enough.
